# Ident Tabs for Multiple New Line String Variable in Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, tabs, streamwriter, .net-core-2.0

How do I ident a set of lines when writing to a file, with a tabs? I need to go through each line in the variable and create 8 spaces or two tabs for each line, when writing to the new file.

If the string was one line, it would be easy, with `"    " + test`,  however this has multiple lines.

```
public static string testLine=
        "Line1" + Environment.NewLine +
        "Line2" + Environment.NewLine +
        "Line3" + Environment.NewLine +
        "Line4" + Environment.NewLine +

 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, true))
 {
        file.WriteLine(testLine);
```

String is composed of new line, line breaks enters, etc .

Is there any Microsoft Ident function library to support this?
Needs to handle multiple string variables in the future.

Comment: You can decompose this line into multiple ones and write them to file in a loop.

Comment: I mean, it's not necessary to create this variable by hand. You can construct it on runtime. I think you will find StringBuilder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) handy enough for this case.

Comment: well, i was given these variables by another team, making use of them now

Comment: well them decompose it into lines first: `var lines = string.Split(Environment.NewLine, testLine)`. And then loop through these lines and write tabs before each.

Comment: ok, feel free to place working code in answer, and I can send points thanks!

Comment: habo, do you have code you can write into an answer? was Looking for the same thing! @HABO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prefix the string with whitespace or a tab and replace all occurences off newlines with a newline and a suitable whitespace:

```
testLine = "    " + testLine.Replace( Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "    " );
```

You can explicitly handle an empty string to avoid indenting nothing:

```
testLine = String.IsNullOrEmpty(testLine) ? testLine : "    " + testLine.Replace( Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "    " );
```

Substitute `"\t"` for `"    "` to insert a tab character.